# Android Xamarin Stripe Integration

Tags: xamarin.android, stripe-payments

I am busy creating an android Xamarin app where users should be able to use Stripe to make a payment for a product. I have used stripe before on our web based platform but can't seem to find any documentation or tutorials on how to integrate stripe into android Xamarin. Is there anyone who can provide some guidance on how to do that?

Comment: About using Stripe in xamarin.android, I find one article that you can take a look:[Bring Android Pay to Your Apps with Stripe](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/bring-android-pay-to-your-apps-with-stripe/)

Comment: Stripe doesn't have any official docs as they don't officially support Xamarin. Any tutorial I've seen tends to use the Charge API which is deprecated in favor of PaymentIntents, so you might be out of luck on how to implement this. I suggest looking at the Android docs instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#android